# Limits with $\ln(a_n)/n$ without Stolz-Cezaro Thm

Tags: calculus, limits

If $a_n$ is a positive, real sequence with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. Then prove that $\frac{\ln(a_n)}{n}=1$. I heard that it could be proved by the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem but I want a more elementrical proof.
What I've tried is trying something like LHT but I don't think that the derivative of such sequence ${a_n}$ is defined. How can I do it?

EDIT : Is the following statement true??
 $\lim_{n\to\inf} a_n=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\inf} a_n^{1/n}$ isn't 0

Comment: Where did you find that result?

Comment: I started with statement $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/n}=0$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true, for example by $a_n=e^{-n}\to 0$ we have

$$\frac{\ln(a_n)}{n}=\frac{\ln(e^{-n})}{n}=-1$$

and by $a_n=e^{-{n^2}}\to 0$ we have

$$\frac{\ln(a_n)}{n}=\frac{\ln(e^{-n^2})}{n}=-n\to -\infty$$

Note that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/n}$$

is not true indeed by $a_n=e^{-n}\to 0$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} (e^{-n})^{1/n}=e^{-1}$$

Comment: Is this true then?? lim n->inf a_n=0 then lim n->inf a_n^{1/n} isn't 0

Comment: Can $\lim_{n\to\inf} a_n^{1/n}=0$??

Comment: @Hypernova Try with $a_n=e^{-{n^2}}\to 0$.